# Как сделать java ползунок с формой?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. У меня возник вопрос, как создать java ползунок без лишнего кода? Желательно чтобы стили были в css файле. Искал по инету - не нашел доступного кода java ползунка.

Comment: А что подразумевается под "java ползунком"?

Answer (score 2):

Через CSS никак. Вот решение на JS http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar

А если чисто для формы то через CSS можно, но в IE не работало раньше

```
.classforform{ 
  scrollbar-face-color: #317B9C;
  scrollbar-track-color: #87B4C9;
  scrollbar-arrow-color: #54A1C4;
  scrollbar-3dlight-color: #B8D7E6;
  scrollbar-shadow-color: #1E6180;
  scrollbar-highlight-color: #7CBCDA;
  scrollbar-darkshadow-color: #1E6180;
}
```